# "Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6" - How to Fix Warning

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I fix this warning in Python/MatPlotLib. The exact warning is --

"MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.
plt.show()"

I am using python 3.11 and Matplotlib version 3.6.2.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from yellowbrick.regressor import ResidualsPlot
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

directory = 'Data'
file = 'Titanic.csv'


#1 and #2
titanic = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, file))
#print(titanic)
# The target variable is if the passenger survived or not. I.e., (Survived)

#3
titanicRelevent = titanic[['Class', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Survived']]
#print(titanicRelevent)

#4
titanicNoNA = titanicRelevent.dropna()
#print(titanicNoNA)

#5
sns.countplot(data=titanicNoNA, x='Class')
plt.show()
sns.countplot(data=titanicNoNA, x='Sex')
plt.show()
sns.countplot(data=titanicNoNA, x='Age')
plt.show()
```